# ajax email function parse error

Tags: php, ajax, email

in my php file I keep getting a parse error on line 5 which is the line that holds the from email in it 
 any ideas why?

```
<?php

$params = array(
    'to' => 'admin@mail.com', 
    'from' => '<noreply@mail.com>' 
);

$name = trim( $_POST['name'] );
$email = trim( $_POST['email'] );
$subject = trim( $_POST['subject'] );
$message = trim( $_POST['message'] );

if ( empty( $name ) or empty( $message ) ) {
    echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'error' ) );
} else if ( empty( $email ) or ! filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {
    echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'email' ) );
} else {
    $headers = 'From: ' . $name . ' ' . $params['from'] . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion( );
    $message = str_replace( array( "\r", "\n" ), array( '', "\r\n" ), $message );

    if ( mail( $params['to'], ( empty( $subject ) ? 'New message without subject' : 'New message: ' . $subject ), $message, $headers ) ) {
        echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'ok' ) );
    } else {
        echo json_encode( array( 'status' => 'error' ) );
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove one **)** from end and try it.
`if ( mail( $params['to'], ( empty( $subject ) ? 'New message without subject' : 'New message: ' . $subject ), $message, $headers ){`

Comment: Now final debug way, cut all code from file after line 5. If error, remove error. Else paste code you have deleted. This time, cut half of remaining code. So on...Using this way, you will get line of error and remove it. `$params = array(
    'to' => 'admin@mail.com', 
    'from' => '<noreply@mail.com>' 
);` I checked this line in my computer there is no error.

Comment: naa i have other sites that email no problem

Comment: I am thinking this has something do with the ajax or js cause I have rewrote this script 5 times and still error. I even wrote a smaller script for the subscribe button only taking in an email and I get the same problem. Here is what the console is showing now. path/to/subscribe.php 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4

Answer (score 0):

Try to quote with "" not ''

```
$params = array(
    "to" => "admin@mail.com", 
    "from" => "<noreply@mail.com>"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the permissions on the files need to be `6 4 4`